# List of custom type in JBehave step

Tags: java, jbehave

**Given** a parameter converter

```
@AsParameterConverter
public MyType toMyType(String myTypeString) {
}
```

**When** I try to run a test having a step

```
@Given("a custom step with a $vals")
public void list(List<MyType> vals) {
}
```

**Then** it should run, but it fails with the following message:

```
No parameter converter for interface java.util.List
org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters$ParameterConvertionFailed: No parameter converter for interface java.util.List
```

Comment: If I replace `List<MyType> vals` to `MyType vals` it works.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, JBehave does not accept arrays as parameters.  You should, instead, pass the variables individually.  If there are too many, then perhaps a different approach should be considered.  I would also recommend using the <> delimiters for parameters instead of $ as I have experienced problems with legacy code using $ finding "duplicate steps" that were not duplicates, but went away when changed to <>.  It is not the cause of your reported error, but I would think you would also have to use the @Named("vals") declaration before the defined parameter type and variable.

I believe the reason that JBehave would not be able to support arrays as parameters is because it would have no way of knowing what to pass.  You might think that perhaps it is the only parameter(s) in the scenario, but what if there were other variables, i.e. vals might be employee info (first name, last name, etc.) and then another step in the same scenario needs, say, a URL.  How could JBehave determine which variables in the list of Examples to pass as "vals" and where to locate "URL" or any other variable?